# Process's father after setpgid(0,0);

Tags: process, system-calls

I have a process **P1** (child of some parent process **P0**) both in the same process group. **P1** somewhere in his code runs: `setpgid(0,0);` then a new process group is created (where the group leader is **P1**).

- Who is now **P1**'s father: still **P0**, the session leader or some other?

Answer (score 5):

Changing process groups has no effect on the process hierarchy. The parent is still **P0**.

It's important that the process hierarchy stays the same. When a shell implements job control, each job is put in its own process group. But the shell must still be the parent of the process group leader, so that the shell gets a `SIGCHLD` signal when it exits.